# Excel VBA Run-time 1004 Ms Excel cannot paste the data

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I am using this Macro to automatically copy and paste a range of cells from one Excel file to another. It seems to be working fine with 8-10 files. But I have to process about 49 files and that is when i face an issue. I get a RUN TIME ERROR 1004: Ms Excel cannot paste data.

Here is the line of code that the debugger takes me to:

```
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 1), Cells(emptyRow, 23))
```

And here is all of the code i am using:

```
Sub AllFilesProject1()
Dim folderPath As String
Dim filename As String
Dim wb As Workbook

folderPath = "C:\Users\enchevay\Desktop\automation\WeeklyReports\"

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"

filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")
Do While filename <> ""
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False


   'copy & paste range of information
   Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
   wb.Worksheets("Report Figures (hidden)").Visible = True
   Worksheets("Report Figures (hidden)").Range("A3:W3").Copy
   emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ActiveWorkbook.Close
   ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 1), Cells(emptyRow, 23))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    filename = Dir
Loop
```

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

I dont understand how sometimes it crashesh on FILE NO18, sometimes on FILE NO 29?Plus the code seems to be working fine when i run it with F8.
 Could you please help me to solve that issue?

Thanks

Comment: Just a guess, but it might be clearing the clipboard when you close a workbook that's relatively large. Instead of pasting after `ActiveWorkbook.Close` try pasting first -- you'll have to create a variable a the top to hold `ActiveSheet` (ex. `dim origWS as WorkSheet : set origWS = activeworksheet`), then origWS.Paste....

Comment: What is the value of emptyRow what this error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few things that seemed wrong with your code. I went ahead and cleaned it up for you. It should correct the errors as well.

Try this!

```
Sub AllFilesProject1()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

    folderPath = "C:\Users\enchevay\Desktop\automation\WeeklyReports\"

    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"

    filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")
    Do While filename <> ""
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        'copy & paste range of information
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
        wb2.Worksheets("Report Figures (hidden)").Visible = True
        emptyrow = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        wb2.Worksheets("Report Figures (hidden)").Range("A3:W3").Copy _
            Destination:=wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyrow, 1), Cells(emptyrow, 23))

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb2.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        filename = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that but i get a Runtime error 1004     its something to do with that line    wb2.Worksheets("Report Figures (hidden)").Range("A3:W3").Copy _
        Destination:=wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 1), Cells(emptyRow, 23))

Comment: There's probably an error in a worksheet name or an unset workbook object. Make sure your worksheets are properly spelled and that your workbooks are well set before the copy.